# How to check by onContentAfterSave it is a article?

Tags: plugin

I have follow code for after save:

```
public function onContentAfterSave ($context, $article, $isNew)
{
$article = JModelLegacy::getInstance('Article', 'ContentModel')->getItem(); 
....
}
```

It works fine if I save an article.
But it will execute too if I save other things like a Weblink, so there comes the error measage:

> Call to a member function getItem() on boolean

Now I'am look for a rule to check that the code only execute by save an article like

```
 public function onContentAfterSave ($context, $article, $isNew)
    {
    if (IS_A_ARTCLE) {  ... }
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You use the $context variable for that. So you have to start your function like this:

```
public function onContentAfterSave ($context, $article, $isNew)
{
  if ($context == "com_content.article") {
      // Your code for articles here
  }
}
```

Comment: Fantastc, THATS it. nexttime I will RTFM. 1000 Thanks